# xml base and relative query combination in qml

Tags: qml

I have the following xml :

```
<response>
<id>...</id>
<category_id>...</category_id>
<name>...</name>
<detail>
    <resource>
        <label>...</label>
        <value>...</value>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <label>...</label>
        <value>...</value>
    </resource>
</detail>
<price>...</price>
<currency>...</currency>
</response>
```

I need to get the id, name as well as label and value from one XmlListModel

I have the following code:

```
XmlListModel {
    id: model
    query:"/response"
    source:"xml source"

    XmlRole { name: "name"; query: "name/string()"  }
    XmlRole { name: "id"; query:"id/number()"  }
    XmlRole { name: "label"; query: "detail/resource/label/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "value"; query:"detail/resource/value/string()" }
}
```

What is wrong with this code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that the xpath query `detail/resource/label/string()` does not select exactly one node, because there are multiple `resource` nodes. If you don't need all `resource` nodes, you can select only the first one with `detail/resource[1]/label/string()`.

If you need all `resource` nodes, you can use an additional `XmlModel`:

```qml
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {

    property string xmlData:
        "<response>
            <id>1234</id>
            <category_id>...</category_id>
            <name>The Name</name>
            <detail>
                <resource>
                    <label>Res1</label>
                    <value>1</value>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <label>Res2</label>
                    <value>2</value>
                </resource>
            </detail>
            <price>...</price>
            <currency>...</currency>
        </response>"

    // model for general data
    XmlListModel {
        id: model

        xml: xmlData

        query:"/response"

        XmlRole { name: "name"; query: "name/string()"  }
        XmlRole { name: "id";   query: "id/number()"  }
    }

    // model for resource data
    XmlListModel {
        id: resModel

        xml: xmlData

        query: "/response/detail/resource"

        XmlRole { name: "label"; query: "label/string()" }
        XmlRole { name: "value"; query: "value/string()" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...
That what I've done exactly but I was looking for a more efficient solution.

Comment: @h_kassem: What should be more efficient? Do you worry about using two `XmlListModel`s instead of one?

Comment: First:the xml contains also photos and something else, so at least I should use 3 to 4 XmlListModel.
Second: I have to make sure that all theses model finish parsing in order to implement a loading function, if I have only one XmlListModel it's more practical, but anyway thanks :)